# Linear independence for a set of real valued continuous functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real valued continuous functions.

Is the following set $\{\cos t, \sin t, \mathrm{e}^t\}$ linearly independent?

---

I usually understand what and how to determine if a set of vectors is linearly independent. My question is how do I treat this sort of set? Usually I would solve for the coefficients in a linear system, i.e. $a_1(\cos t) + a_2(\sin t) + a_3(\mathrm{e}^t) = 0$, but I can't see how that would help here, unless it is just that obvious that these vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a\cos t + b\sin t +ce^t \equiv 0.$ Then $c= 0,$ otherwise the left side is unbounded as $t \to \infty,$ hardly the behavior of the zero function. So now we know $c=0,$ hence $a\cos t + b\sin t\equiv 0.$ Plug in some simple values of $t$ ($t=0$ comes to mind for one) to see $a,b = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let us compute some particular values: $\cos(0)=1$, $\sin(0)=0$, $e^0=1$; $\cos(\pi)=-1$, $\sin(\pi)=0$, $e^\pi=e^\pi$; $\cos(0.5\pi)=0$, $\sin(0,5\pi)=1$, $e^{0.5\pi}=e^{0.5\pi}$. The matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\-1&0&e^\pi\\0&1&e^{0.5\pi}\end{pmatrix}$$ is non-singular, so that your functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the functions are linearly dependent if there exist $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, not all zero, such that the equality$$a\sin(t)+b\cos(t)+ce^t=0$$holds for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$. By substituting different values of $t$, one obtains infinitely many linear equations in $a,b,c$. You just need to determine whether or not these equations have a non-trivial common solution.

Comment: So if i gather what you are saying is that it is dependent on my value of t and what that gives me in order to determine if the vectors are linearly independent? If that is the case then, how do i expound on that to a general case?

Comment: @dc3rd I don't understand. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I did some more work on it and i think i completely understand now. In a case where my vectors are linearly dependent, my coefficients that i obtain are going to depend on whatever the "t" value is? For instance say i had a set of linearly dependent vectors, S,  and i wanted to write one of the vectors from my set S as a linear combination of the remaining vectors in S. What i am asking is that my exact coefficients are going to be in terms of "t"? For example say $a_2 = \frac {t - e^t}{sin (t) - e^t} $ is a coefficient i solved for.

Comment: @dc3rd No, the exact opposite is true. In order for the functions to be linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$, the coefficients need to be the same for every value of $t$.

Comment: Ugh now i am confused. What i did was i set up a linear combination with my vectors, then took that combinations first derivative and second derivative, then i used those three equations to solve for the 3 coefficients. But now you are saying all those coefficients have to be the same?